# HXT: Adding elements to a tree based on a list

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm struggling using arrows in the HXT library to generate elements in a tree based on a list (the line with mapM below).

```
mkqelem (mkQName vns "depositInstruction" pacNS) []  
    [selem "key" 
        [selem "accountId" [txt $ pacuAccountId pacUpdate],
         selem "instructionId" [txt $ pacuInstructionId pacUpdate]
        ],
     selem "totalAmount" [txt $ pacuTotalAmount pacUpdate],
     mapM mkInvestment  [(120, 10.0)]
     ]

mkInvestment :: ArrowXml a => (Fund, Amount) -> a n XmlTree
mkInvestment x = selem "investments" [selem "investmentId" [txt $ show $ fst x],selem "amount" [txt $ show $ snd x]]
```

The program won't compile, I get the following:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘XN.NTree’
  Expected type: a n XmlTree
    Actual type: a n [XmlTree]
• In the expression: mapM mkInvestment [(120, 10.0)]
  In the third argument of ‘mkqelem’, namely
    ‘[mkelem
        "key" [] [selem "accountId" [...], selem "instructionId" [...]],
      selem "totalAmount" [txt $ pacuTotalAmount pacUpdate],
      mapM mkInvestment [(120, 10.0)]]’
  In the expression:
    mkqelem
      (mkQName vns "depositInstruction" pacNS)
      []
      [mkelem
         "key" [] [selem "accountId" [...], selem "instructionId" [...]],
       selem "totalAmount" [txt $ pacuTotalAmount pacUpdate],
       mapM mkInvestment [(120, 10.0)]]
```

I've tried replacing mapM with variations of +=, but I don't have a good intuition on mapping in Arrows. Any pointers?

Comment: What's the behaviour of this program? Include any errors. If it compiles and runs without error (but the behaviour is incorrect) then include the desired behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the compiler error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue doesn't actually involve arrows; rather, it has to do with `mapM` being unnecessary here. A plain `fmap` over the list of tuples to make the element arrows, following by appending the result to the list with the rest of your elements, should be enough.

```
mkqelem (mkQName vns "depositInstruction" pacNS) [] $
    [selem "key" 
        [selem "accountId" [txt $ pacuAccountId pacUpdate],
         selem "instructionId" [txt $ pacuInstructionId pacUpdate]
        ],
     selem "totalAmount" [txt $ pacuTotalAmount pacUpdate]
     ]
    ++ fmap mkInvestment [(120, 10.0), (121, 15.0)]
```

As for `(+=)`, it adds children to a node, so you wouldn't use it instead of `mapM`/`fmap`, but rather, for instance, to define `mkInvestment` in a different manner:

```
mkInvestment :: ArrowXml a => (Fund, Amount) -> a n XmlTree
mkInvestment x = eelem "investments"
    += (eelem "investmentId" += (txt $ show $ fst x))
    += (eelem "amount" += (txt $ show $ snd x))
    -- Minor style suggestion: you might prefer to use pattern matching here 
    -- instead of fst and snd.
```

Comment: Ahh, that worked, thanks... the trick for me was understanding that I can use fmap there.

Answer (score 1):

Your top code listing has a comma which is not present in the code printed by GHC in the error message.  Without the comma, GHC tries to interpret `mapM`, `mkInvestment`,  and `[(120, 10.0)]` as three arguments to `selem`.

I haven't tried compiling with the comma; I don't know if there are additional errors.

Comment: Sorry, silly error on my part... the error message has been updated after I fixed the comma issue.